# Showing map in Processing and displaying Tweets based on their Lat and Lon coordinates?

Tags: twitter, processing

Will anyone please help me in displaying a world map on Processing and then plotting tweets on corresponding locations?

Comment: That's a big question. Do you have a preferred way to do this? Presumably you want to put this in a web page? In that case, I'd recommend D3.js, http://d3js.org/

Comment: If not for web, http://twitter4j.org and http://unfoldingmaps.org can be handy. I've done that using this tools.

Comment: @bbill D3 is a good recommendation, but Fari says they wan't to use Processing...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an entire answer, but should show how to plot the locations on a world map. Note the getPoint() method that does the Cartesian coordinates (you could do the same with the map() function in Processing.Also note the constructor does the calculations to size the image of the earth you use to the sketch window...

```
WorldMap world;
Point[] cities = new Point[6];

void setup() {
  size(800, 480);
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1.5);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  smooth();

  // World
  world = new WorldMap(0, 0, width, height);

  // Cities
  cities[0] = world.getPoint(45.24, -75.43);  // Ottawa
  cities[1] = world.getPoint(38.53, -77.02);  // Washington
  cities[2] = world.getPoint(51.32, 0.50);    // London
  cities[3] = world.getPoint(48.48, 2.20);    // Paris
  cities[4] = world.getPoint(39.55, 116.25);  // Beijing
  cities[5] = world.getPoint(35.40, 139.45);  // Tokyo

}

void draw() {

  world.drawBackground();

  for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    ellipse(cities[i].x, cities[i].y, 10, 10);
  }

}

//-------------------------------

class WorldMap {

  int x, y, w, h;
  PImage raster;

   WorldMap(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
     // Scale Image
     if (h >= w/2) {
       this.w = w;
       this.h = w/2;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = (h - this.h)/2;
     } 
     else {
       this.h = h;
       this.w = 2*h;
       this.x = (w - this.w)/2;
       this.y = y;
     }

     // Load Image
     raster = loadImage("world_longlatwgs3.png");
  }

 void drawBackground() {
   image(raster, x, y, w, h);
  }

 Point getPoint(float phi, float lambda) {
   Point pt = new Point(x + ((180 + lambda) / 360) * w, y + h - ((90 + phi) / 180) * h);
   return pt;
  }

}

//-------------------------------

class Point extends Point2D {
  Point(float x, float y) { 
    super(x, y); 
  }
}

class Point2D {
  float x, y;
  Point2D(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Fari please consider accepting or upvoting this answer if it is helpful - or post your own answer if you worked this out! Acknowledgement of other's work goes a long way to having people answer your questions in the future !